# Print pre formatted Array without <pre> tag

Tags: php, arrays, formatted

here is my problem:

I want output a formatted array on my webserver, like this:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "motd": "    [  Mineplex Games  ]    \n        \u2744 New Game \u2744 Gladiators \u2744",
    "version": "1.8",
    "players": {
        "online": 24410,
        "max": 24411
    },
    "ping": "0.039",
    "cache": 1450047242
}
```

In the source of that page there is not `<pre>` tag, but I don't know how to reproduce that result without that tag.

How can I do that? Here is my code

```
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($array);
  echo '</pre>';
```

EDIT: `echo json_encode($array);` will output a non-formatted text, just a line.

Comment: That's JSON, not a PHP array, and it must have some kind of pre-formatting tag or styles added to it for it to render that way unless you're just looking at the source code

Comment: echo json_encode($array); will output a non-formatted text, just a line.

Comment: If you're working on a JSON string, then you'll need to convert it to a PHP array first with json_decode.

Comment: Are you saying print_r works fine with `pre` but doesn't work without `pre`? That is because your page is rendering in HTML which treats redundant whitespace as a single space thus ignoring linebreaks. If you clicked "view source" of your HTML page, you'll see print_r doesn't output it on a single line, it actually uses multiple lines. You can similarly use `header("Content-Type:text/plain");` at the top of your page to make the spacing meaningful. If you need the newlines `\n` to be converted to `<br>` there's http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to set a mime-type other than `text/html`. try `text/plain` (will show like when used html with `<pre>`) for example or `application/json` (the official type for json)

In PHP, use the following lines:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Which content-type did you finally use?

Answer (score 1):

That is JSON, try `echo json_encode($array);`

edit: For a formatted result, json_encode takes a second parameter.

Try this `echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to add line breaks between elements, you can can try:

```
echo implode("<br>", $array);
```

Comment: i don't  want html tags in the page! it's like the page should download array.json file

Comment: You could output the array to a file named something.txt and redirect the user to that file. Text files render verbatim in most browsers, including line breaks, without html.